# Add Row Values to DataTable Having AutoIncreamented DataColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a row in a DataTable having a Data Column which has an auto Increament Property.

```
DataTable tblproduct = new DataTable();

DataColumn CartItemId = new DataColumn();
CartItemId.ColumnName = "CartItemId";
CartItemId.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
CartItemId.AutoIncrement = true;
CartItemId.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
CartItemId.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
CartItemId.ReadOnly = true;
CartItemId.Unique = true;

tblproduct.Columns.Add(CartItemId);
tblproduct.Columns.Add("CampaignId", typeof(int));
tblproduct.Columns.Add("SubCatId", typeof(int));
tblproduct.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
tblproduct.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));

tblproduct.Rows.Add(3, 345,"Hello", 1);
tblproduct.Rows.Add(5, 3455,"Hecfghhgdfllo", 8);
```

I don't want to insert the values in Autoincreamented column. It should be Autogenerated value but above code didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When adding the row, rather try something like

```
        DataRow dr = tblproduct.NewRow();
        dr["CampaignId"] = 3;
        dr["SubCatId"] = 345;
        dr["Size"] = "Hello";
        dr["Qty"] = 1;
        tblproduct.Rows.Add(dr);
```

also from [DataColumn.AutoIncrement Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> You can create a new row using the ItemArray property of the DataRow
>   class and passing in an array of values. **This is a potential problem
>   for a column with its AutoIncrement set to true, because its value is
>   generated automatically. To use the ItemArray property, place null in
>   the column's position in the array.**

change your code to something like

```
        tblproduct.Rows.Add(null,3, 345, "Hello", 1);
        tblproduct.Rows.Add(null,5, 3455, "Hecfghhgdfllo", 8);
```